# How do I make this bottom sheet scrollable and show submit button covered by keyboard?

Tags: flutter

I want to render a bottom sheet modal but the keyboard covers the submit button and I cannot scroll to access it.

Here is what I tried but not getting the expected result. The result I am getting is the keyboard covering the submit button and I cannot scroll to it.

//report_issue_bs_widget.dart

```
import 'package:careforce/ux/views/account/widgets/image_upload_item.dart';
import 'package:careforce/ux/views/account/widgets/image_upload_placeholder.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import '../../resources/app_colors.dart';
import '../../resources/app_dimens.dart';
import '../../resources/app_strings.dart';
import '../shared/app_button.dart';
import '../shared/bottom_sheet_widget.dart';

void reportIssueBottomSheet({
  required BuildContext context,
}) {
  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
  int maxCharacters = 10;
  int maxImageLength = 3;
  int uploadedImageCount = 0;
  int remainingCharacters = maxCharacters;

  void updateRemainingCharacters(StateSetter setState, String text) {
    setState(() {
      remainingCharacters =
          (maxCharacters - text.length).clamp(0, maxCharacters);
    });

    if (remainingCharacters == 0) {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
    }
  }

  List<Image?> uploadedImages = List.filled(3, null);

  Image? getImageFromCamera() {
    return Image.asset("assets/images/issue_icon.jpg");
  }

  showBottomSheetModal(
    context,
    StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (ctx, setState) => SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: AppDimens.defaultMargin,
          ),
          padding:
              const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: AppDimens.defaultMargin),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: AppDimens.defaultMarginMediumSmall,
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      const Spacer(),
                      GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: const Text(
                          AppStrings.close,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: AppDimens.normalFontSize,
                            color: AppColors.colorPrimary,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  constraints: BoxConstraints(
                    maxHeight: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
                        AppDimens.defaultBackdropHeight),
                  ),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: AppDimens.defaultMarginMedium,
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          AppStrings.reportAnIssue,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              fontSize: AppDimens.titleFontSize),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: AppDimens.defaultMarginSmall,
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          AppStrings.reportAnIssueSubtext,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                              fontSize: AppDimens.fontSizeTwelve),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: AppDimens.defaultMarginLarge,
                        ),
                        RichText(
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          text: const TextSpan(
                            text: AppStrings.whatWentWrongText,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: AppColors.black,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                            ),
                            children: [
                              TextSpan(
                                text: " *",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: AppColors.brightRed,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: AppDimens.defaultMarginSmall,
                        ),
                        TextField(
                          controller: controller,
                          maxLines: 5,
                          inputFormatters: [
                            LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(maxCharacters),
                          ],
                          onChanged: (text) {
                            updateRemainingCharacters(setState, text);
                          },
                          decoration: const InputDecoration(
                            filled: true,
                            fillColor: AppColors.lighterGrey,
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: AppColors.lighterGreyBorder, width: 1),
                            ),
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: AppColors.lighterGreyBorder, width: 1),
                            ),
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                  color: AppColors.lighterGreyBorder, width: 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: AppDimens.defaultMarginExtraSmall,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Text(
                            '${AppStrings.charactersRemaining} : $remainingCharacters',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: AppColors.mediumDarkerGrey,
                              fontSize: AppDimens.fontSizeTwelve,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: AppDimens.defaultMarginLarge),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            RichText(
                              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                              text: const TextSpan(
                                text: AppStrings.photoEvidence,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: AppColors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                ),
                                children: [
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: " (${AppStrings.optionalText})",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: AppColors.lightGrey,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "$uploadedImageCount/$maxImageLength",
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                color: AppColors.colorPrimary,
                                fontSize: AppDimens.fontSizeTwelve,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: AppDimens.defaultMarginSmall),
                        const Text(
                          AppStrings.photoEvidenceDescriptionText,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: AppColors.mediumDarkGrey,
                            fontSize: AppDimens.fontSizeTwelve,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: AppDimens.defaultMarginSmall),
                        const Text(
                          AppStrings.photoUploadInstruction,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: AppColors.mediumDarkGrey,
                            fontSize: AppDimens.fontSizeTwelve,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: AppDimens.defaultMargin),
                        SingleChildScrollView(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          child: Row(
                            children: List.generate(3, (index) {
                              if (uploadedImages[index] == null) {
                                if (index == 0 ||
                                    uploadedImages[index - 1] != null) {
                                  return ImageUploadPlaceholder(
                                    onAddImage: () {
                                      setState(() {
                                        Image? image = getImageFromCamera();
                                        uploadedImages[index] = image;
                                        uploadedImageCount++;
                                      });
                                    },
                                  );
                                } else {
                                  return Container();
                                }
                              } else {
                                return ImageUploadItem(
                                  image: uploadedImages[index]!.image,
                                  onRemove: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      uploadedImages[index] = null;
                                      uploadedImageCount--;
                                    });
                                  },
                                );
                              }
                            }),
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: AppDimens.defaultMargin),
                        const Text(
                          AppStrings.photoUploadInstruction,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: AppColors.mediumDarkGrey,
                            fontSize: AppDimens.fontSizeTwelve,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: AppDimens.defaultMarginLargeExtra),
                        PrimaryButton(
                          enabled: controller.text.isNotEmpty,
                          onTap: () {
                            // onTap(controller.text);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            AppStrings.submit.toUpperCase(),
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: AppDimens.normalFontSize,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

//bottom_sheet_widget.dart

```
import 'package:careforce/ux/resources/app_colors.dart';
import 'package:careforce/ux/resources/app_dimens.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

showBottomSheetModal(BuildContext context, Widget child,
    {Color? backgroundColor,
    double cornerRadius = AppDimens.bottomSheetBorderRadius}) {
  showModalBottomSheet(
    context: context,
    isScrollControlled: true,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
        topLeft: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
        topRight: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
      ),
    ),
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: [
                // content
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: backgroundColor ?? AppColors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
                      topRight: Radius.circular(cornerRadius),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Center(
                        child: Container(
                          width: AppDimens.bottomSheetDragIndicatorWidth,
                          height: AppDimens.bottomSheetDragIndicatorHeight,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: AppDimens.defaultMargin),
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: AppColors.lightFontGrey.withOpacity(0.3),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                              AppDimens.defaultBorderRadius,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      // content
                      child,
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```